# replace all characters in a string with a new character, except blank in R

Tags: r, string, str-replace

I have a string, for example:
`str <- c("a string","of words","also some spaces")`
and I'd like to turn them into
`strx <- c("x xxxxxx","xx xxxxx","xxxx xxxx xxxxxx")`

I only have thoughts on count the length using str_length() to get the number of characters of each string. Then I'm out of ideas, please help. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We can match a non-white space character (`\\S`) and replace with `x` using `gsub` in `base R`

```
gsub("\\S", "x", str)
#[1] "x xxxxxx"         "xx xxxxx"         "xxxx xxxx xxxxxx"
```